# get and display peripheral bluetooth RSSI signal strength in IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having trouble within an IOS swift application trying to get bluetooth RSSI signal strength from the peripheral. I've been trying to use readRSSI() (see code below) which returns a Future, but I've so far been unable to map that Future into another usable variable such as an Int or String. I'm new to Swift, so not sure if I'm missing an async step or other. I'm used to working in R, python, JS and having some challenges wrapping my head around the syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've tried switching multiple ways of extracting the content from within extensions to the ViewController without luck. I get errors on type-mismatches no matter how I try to pass the Future type value.

```swift
let strengthCharacteristic = self.peripheral.readRSSI()
let thisRet = self.strengthChar.map({ avar in 
    return avar
})
self.strengthLabel.text = String(thisRet ?? 0)
```

Comment: You need to use the peripheral(_:didReadRSSI:error:) method on the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1519111-readrssi?language=objc) for readRSSI() method:

> On iOS and tvOS, when you call this method to retrieve the RSSI of the peripheral while connected to the central manager, the peripheral calls the peripheral:didReadRSSI:error: method of its delegate object, which includes the RSSI value as a parameter.

In order to read the RSSI from a peripheral, implement the peripheral:didReadRSSI:error: in the delegate object of the peripheral. This method will be fired when you call the readRSSI() method of the peripheral object. You can retrieve the RSSI value directly in this method as an input parameter. Don't forget to assign the delegate to the peripheral object.